# Increment item count of specific item in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am able to increase my quantity using the code below but I have a problem with it. It only  increases once and decreases once, and when i click on `add` it increases perfectly but when it comes to decreasing, it decreases 2 values at a time

**example** 
add-> 1+1=2 
but 
sub -> 2-1=0

**CartFragment**

```
     cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(getContext(), cartData.getProducts(), this);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        productCartRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
        productCartRecyclerview.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
```

**Listener**

```
  @Override
    public void addQuantity(int position, TextView quantity) {

        productQuantity= cartData.getProducts().get(position).getQuantity();
        productQuantity++;
        quantity.setText(""+productQuantity);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+productQuantity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void subQuantity(int position, TextView quantity) {

        productQuantity= cartData.getProducts().get(position).getQuantity();
        productQuantity--;
        quantity.setText(""+productQuantity);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+productQuantity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Cart Adapter**

```
    public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> myArrayList;
    private QuantityManipulation  quantityManipulation;

    public CartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> myArrayList,QuantityManipulation  quantityManipulation ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.myArrayList = myArrayList;
        this.quantityManipulation=quantityManipulation;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cart,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product  product = myArrayList.get(position);
        holder.cartTitle.setText(product.getProductName());
        holder.primaryModifier.setText(""+product.getModifier1());
        holder.secondaryModifier.setText(""+product.getModifier2());
      //  holder.cartSize.setText(product.get);
        holder.cartPrice.setText(""+product.getProductBasePrice());
        holder.cartQunatity.setText(""+product.getQuantity());
        Picasso.get().load(product.getImageUrl()).into(holder.cartImage);


       /* holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int quantity;
                quantity = product.getQuantity();
                quantity++;
                holder.cartQunatity.setText(""+quantity);
            }
        });

        holder.sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int quantity;
               quantity = product.getQuantity();
                if (product.getQuantity() > 1){
                    quantity--;
                    holder.cartQunatity.setText(""+quantity);
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, ""+quantity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myArrayList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView  cartTitle;
        TextView primaryModifier;
        TextView cartPrice;
        TextView cartQunatity;
        TextView cartSize;
        ImageView cartImage;
        TextView secondaryModifier;
        ImageView add;
        ImageView sub;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cartTitle =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcartTitle);

            primaryModifier =itemView.findViewById(R.id.primarymodifier);
            secondaryModifier = itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondaryModifier);

            cartSize =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcartSize);
            cartQunatity =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCartQuntity);
            cartPrice =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCartPrice);
            cartImage =itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartImageView);
            add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textQuntityAdd);
            sub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textQuntitySub);

            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    quantityManipulation.addQuantity(getAdapterPosition(),cartQunatity);

                }
            });

            sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    quantityManipulation.subQuantity(getAdapterPosition(),cartQunatity);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**Interface Listener**

```
public interface QuantityManipulation {

    void addQuantity(int position, TextView quantity);
    void subQuantity(int position, TextView quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're copying the `productQuantity` and incrementing the copy:

```
productQuantity++;
```

So `cartData.getProducts().get(position).getQuantity();` is always `1`, so adding always gets you `2`, and subtracting always gets you `0`.

You need to set the product's quantity to incremented quantity, probably via some sort of `setQuantity` method (which you may have to write).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. 
 how ? can you demonstrate?

Comment: one of my problems solved. .no it decreases and increases properly. but it still not adding more values.  it  only decreases and increases the counter  1 value over and 1 value lesser

Comment: It sounds like this fixed your problem and now you're having a different problem. If you found this answer helpful, please upvote and/or accept the answer.  Further problems are probably best addressed as a second question, as it's hard to describe problems adequately in a comment thread.

Comment: Buddy read my question again i have 2 questions init, one of my question's answer given my the #Praful and second question still unanswered so buddy how can i accept ur answer, btw i appreciate your answer as well :)

Comment: Asking multiple questions at once is discouraged because it makes answering them difficult for exactly this reason.  I have no idea what your second question is.

Comment: thanks, buddy I'm not a frequent questioner at stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
@Override
    public void subQuantity(int position, TextView quantity) {

        productQuantity= cartData.getProducts().get(position).getQuantity(); //remove this
        productQuantity--;
        quantity.setText(""+productQuantity);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+productQuantity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and productQuantity varialble to declare to global and when load this page assign `productQuantity = cartData.getProducts().get(position).getQuantity()`.

Comment: but if I declared global variable from where i can get the position ?  
//productQuantity = cartData.getProducts().get(??????).getQuantity()

Comment: remove this code **productQuantity= cartData.getProducts().get(position).getQuantity();** from **subQuantity()** method.
could you try this??

Comment: yes, I have tried but its not working, if i remove this line from my method the quantity factor doesn't work. :|

Comment: this `productQuantity= cartData.getProducts().get(position).getQuantity();`code not call every time call when click on add OR subtract qty. because when click on this its always return old qty. So you can write this code only one time call when your fragment is called.

Comment: thanks for your help buddy. i remove these listener and do this work in my viewHolder and if working fine but there is still a problem :| my quantity is not increase after two counts 11,12.. ... 12, 

//my Adapter (ViewHolder) Now
 ///holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    quantity = product.getQuantity();
                    quantity++;
                    holder.cartQunatity.setText(""+quantity);
                }
            });

Comment: then try to add code `product.setQuantity(quantity)` after `quantity++` .